# How to escape paths for findfile() and finddir()?

Tags: vimscript, filesystem

I have run into an escaping problem with the `path` argument to `findfile({name}, {path})` / `finddir({name}, {path})`.

In my [code](https://github.com/airblade/vim-rooter/blob/42a97c624f4f9465703558bf004b013bc36facdb/plugin/rooter.vim#L81-L90) `path` is a directory, obtained via `fnamemodify(<file>, ':h')`.

Until recently I used `fnameescape()` to escape this path, before appending a semi-colon and passing it into `findfile()` / `finddir()`.

However it turned out to [break](https://github.com/airblade/vim-rooter/issues/80) `findfile()` / `finddir()` with filenames containing `#`, because the `#` was escaped but evidently `findfile()` / `finddir()` don't unescape the `#`.

The docs for `findfile()` / `finddir()` don't talk about escaping.  However they do say if the path argument is omitted, they use the value of the `path` option.  The docs for the `path` option say spaces, commas, and backslashes have to be escaped with a backslash.

So I updated my code like this:

```
- fnameescape(dir)
+ escape(dir, ' ,\')
```

But this now breaks on Windows because it escapes backslashes (I think that's why).

What's the correct way to escape file paths for the `findfile()` / `finddir()` functions?

Comment: The space, comma and backslash have a special meaning to `:set`. The space can separate different options names, the comma can separate different values given to an option, and the backslash tell `:set` to disable the special meaning of the next character, which allows you to include a comma/space/backslash inside a value. You probably need to escape the spaces because they have a special meaning on the shell command-line. As for the backslashes, if they cause an issue, you should probably remove them from `escape()`.

Comment: So, I'm not sure it would fix your issue, but I would try to use `escape()` like you did, but only to escape spaces. Btw, that's what tpope does in [fugitive](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive/blob/a9100fafb8c6deb187ee1cfaa37a4a02018d6c9a/autoload/fugitive.vim#L3209), [eunuch](https://github.com/tpope/vim-eunuch/blob/10da325fb032a1acfa9222d273459f53bad30ba4/plugin/eunuch.vim#L30), and [dispatch](https://github.com/tpope/vim-dispatch/blob/fe48d002ce5d473b2057641666d643c66ede6230/autoload/dispatch.vim#L615). He uses something like `findfile('some_file', escape(dir, ' '))`.

Comment: I forgot about the commas. They don't have a special meaning for `findfile()` (only for `:set`), so there's no reason to include them in `escape()`.

Comment: @user938271 Thank you!  I hadn't appreciated that the escaping in the `path` docs was for the benefit of `:set`.  The links to fugitive, eunuch, and dispatch are helpful too.

Comment: @user938271 If you write your comments as an answer I'll be able to accept it :)

Comment: Thanks, but I'm just guessing. I don't know which utility/algorithm `findfile()` uses, nor why the backslash causes an issue in your case. So, I prefer letting someone else with more knowledge on the subject answer the question.